# How to get the last (per date) joined row for each result with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Here is what I want to achieve :

I have a Formation model which have FormationSession model. 
I need all formations with, for each, the last session in database.

Here is what I got so far :

```
$formations = Formation::query()
    ->with('location')
    ->with('jobs')
    ->with('employee')
    ->with('intervenant.company')
    ->with(['formation_sessions' => function($query) {
        $query->limit(1)->orderBy('start_at', 'desc');
    }])
    ->whereNotNull('update_frequency')
    ->get();
```

I'm pretty stuck here, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another relationship something like

```
public function formation_sessions_last(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\FormationSession','formation_id')
                ->orderBy('start_at')->limit(1);
}
#App\FormationSession  => FormationSession Modal
#formation_id          => foreign_key
```

Then you can call query

```
->with('formation_sessions_last')
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: In my case it was :
 
$this->hasMany('App\FormationSession')->orderBy('start_at', 'DESC')->limit(1); 

Thanks, that worked perfectly.